# C# Portable Class Library Equivalent of System.Diagnostics.StackTrace

Tags: c#, debugging, portable-class-library

A program I am working on has a logging function appropriately named "Error," to notify of errors without crashing the program, however, I would like to include a stack trace so these non-fatal errors can be more easily debugged. My first instinct was to use `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace`, which is unfortunately not available in PCL's.

Then, I tried to throw and promptly catch an exception.

```
try { throw new Exception(); } 
catch (Exception ex) { return ex.StackTrace; }
```

Unfortunately, this only provides the top of the call stack: as it does not unravel the stack on its way down, it doesn't provide any useful information. So, my question is this: **How do I get a stack trace in a c# PCL function without throwing an error and catching it at the bottom of the stack?** I would prefer to keep the code entirely in the PCL and avoid using abstractions and platform specific implementation code for something so trivial.

Edit as a response to a comment: `throw new Exception(ex) Only adds another layer to the stack trace, so it has two lines in the stack trace function but still fails to retrieve the full trace.

Comment: I think you are mostly out of luck here. Does `ex.ToString()` include the stack trace? You might have to make do with that. Or perhaps `throw new Exception(ex);`

Comment: The former doesn't but let me go try the latter and update the question.